# Magick++/NAPI module memory leak

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, magick++, node-addon-api

I'm writing a native module using node-addon-api that takes advantage of the Magick++ library. The module takes a file path to an image alongside some parameters and returns a buffer. I seem to have come across a pretty bad memory leak issue which Massif reports as being related to either the buffer that is created or the Magick++ image. Here's my C++ code:

```cpp
#include <napi.h>
#include <list>
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

class FlipWorker : public Napi::AsyncWorker {
 public:
  FlipWorker(Napi::Function& callback, string in_path, bool flop, string type, int delay)
      : Napi::AsyncWorker(callback), in_path(in_path), flop(flop), type(type), delay(delay) {}
  ~FlipWorker() {}

  void Execute() {
    list<Image> frames;
    list<Image> coalesced;
    list<Image> mid;
    list<Image> result;
    readImages(&frames, in_path);
    coalesceImages(&coalesced, frames.begin(), frames.end());

    for (Image &image : coalesced) {
      flop ? image.flop() : image.flip();
      image.magick(type);
      mid.push_back(image);
    }

    optimizeImageLayers(&result, mid.begin(), mid.end());
    if (delay != 0) for_each(result.begin(), result.end(), animationDelayImage(delay));
    writeImages(result.begin(), result.end(), &blob);
  }

  void OnOK() {
    Callback().Call({Env().Undefined(), Napi::Buffer<char>::Copy(Env(), (char *)blob.data(), blob.length())});
  }

 private:
  string in_path, type;
  bool flop;
  int delay;
  Blob blob;
};

Napi::Value Flip(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();

  Napi::Object obj = info[0].As<Napi::Object>();
  Napi::Function cb = info[1].As<Napi::Function>();
  string path = obj.Get("path").As<Napi::String>().Utf8Value();
  bool flop = obj.Has("flop") ? obj.Get("flop").As<Napi::Boolean>().Value() : false;
  string type = obj.Get("type").As<Napi::String>().Utf8Value();
  int delay = obj.Get("delay").As<Napi::Number>().Int32Value();

  FlipWorker* flipWorker = new FlipWorker(cb, path, flop, type, delay);
  flipWorker->Queue();
  return env.Undefined();
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
  exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "flip"), Napi::Function::New(env, Flip));
  return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(addon, Init);
```

And an example JS script:

```js
const image = require("./build/Release/image.node");

setInterval(() => {
  image.flip({ path: "/home/esm/animated.gif", type: "gif", delay: 0 }, (error, buffer) => {
    console.log(buffer);
    console.log(process.memoryUsage().rss);
  });
}, 10000);
```

Here is a sample output of the script:

```
<Buffer 47 49 46 38 39 61 80 02 66 01 f7 00 00 38 44 3a 62 58 26 70 64 27 12 1c 4d 19 26 50 26 30 57 10 38 79 2c 37 67 35 51 57 14 47 79 35 4a 71 55 4f 4f 68 ... 868294 more bytes>
69496832
<Buffer 47 49 46 38 39 61 80 02 66 01 f7 00 00 38 44 3a 62 58 26 70 64 27 12 1c 4d 19 26 50 26 30 57 10 38 79 2c 37 67 35 51 57 14 47 79 35 4a 71 55 4f 4f 68 ... 868294 more bytes>
110673920
<Buffer 47 49 46 38 39 61 80 02 66 01 f7 00 00 38 44 3a 62 58 26 70 64 27 12 1c 4d 19 26 50 26 30 57 10 38 79 2c 37 67 35 51 57 14 47 79 35 4a 71 55 4f 4f 68 ... 868294 more bytes>
152092672
<Buffer 47 49 46 38 39 61 80 02 66 01 f7 00 00 38 44 3a 62 58 26 70 64 27 12 1c 4d 19 26 50 26 30 57 10 38 79 2c 37 67 35 51 57 14 47 79 35 4a 71 55 4f 4f 68 ... 868294 more bytes>
192970752
<Buffer 47 49 46 38 39 61 80 02 66 01 f7 00 00 38 44 3a 62 58 26 70 64 27 12 1c 4d 19 26 50 26 30 57 10 38 79 2c 37 67 35 51 57 14 47 79 35 4a 71 55 4f 4f 68 ... 868294 more bytes>
204517376
```

As you can see, the resident set size increases significantly each time the function is run. This happens with every image in any format that I use with it. How would I keep the code from leaking? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I did some more digging and it turns out that since the buffer is not created through JS, it isn't eligible for garbage collection in the same way. I'm now wondering whether or not it's possible to create a buffer that gets garbage collected by V8 and still provides the same data.

Comment: If you wait for more iterations, does memory consumption go down eventually (indicating the garbage collector kicking in), or does the process eventually crash with out-of-memory?

Comment: @jmrk The process seems to crash with an out of memory error.